# read multiple name value pair from xml tag

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, awk

I have an xml tag where it has multiple name and value pairs

here is my xml tag from my file

```
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.service.http" level="WARN"/>
```

using below command to read

1. AsyncLogger name and its value
2. log level and its value

```
cat log4j2.xml | perl -e 'while (<>) { next if (/<!--.*-->/);if (/<!--/) { while (<>) {last if (/-->/) }}else {print "$_"; }} ' | xmllint --format -| grep org.mule.service.http|awk -F'=' '{print $2,$4}'
```

this is what it is printing

```
"org.mule.service.http" level
```

Expecting output with comma separated

```
org.mule.service.http,WARN
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'concat(//AsyncLogger/@name, ",", //AsyncLogger/@level)' file.xml
org.mule.service.http,WARN
```

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'concat(//AsyncLogger/@name, ",", //AsyncLogger/@level)' /tmp/file.xml
org.mule.service.http,WARN
```

Answer (score 2):

Such XML snippets are easily processed with a library, for instance [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -wnE'
    $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $_); 
    for ( $xml->findnodes("//*") ) {
        @attr = $_->attributes; 
        say "Attributes for node: ", $_->nodeName;
        say for @attr
    }
' file.xml
```

With the string shown in the question as a line in the file `file.xml` this prints

```
Attributes for node: AsyncLogger
 name="org.mule.service.http"
 level="WARN"
```

This is a demo since I'm not sure what the input is like and what output is needed. Browse methods of use in [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod), a base class of `XML::LibXML` nodes.

If you indeed just need comma-separated values of attributes for each node

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -wnE'
    $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $_); 
    for ( $xml->findnodes("//*") ) { 
        say join ",", map { $_->nodeValue } $_->attributes
    }
' file.xml
```

This prints

```
org.mule.service.http,WARN
```

Note that we never need node names or anything such; this can be used on any xml.

The code can be squeezed further,<sup>†</sup> and can also be simplified as the input seems to be mere snippets with a single node each. But I'd rather recommend putting this program in a file what will make it documented, far nicer, and more flexible.

---

<sup>†</sup> For example, in one statement

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -wnE'say join(",", map { $_->nodeValue } $_->attributes)
    for XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $_)->findnodes("//*")' file.xml
```

However, better write out the program nicely in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xpath` with `concat()` and `string()` functions:

```
$ xpath -q -e 'concat(string(//AsyncLogger/@name), ",", string(//AsyncLogger/@level))' file.xml
org.mule.service.http,WARN
```

Require `libxml-xpath-perl` debian package or `XML::XPath` Perl module.

Not installed by default

Answer (score 1):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used for your task.
It is a YAML processor and can also deal with XML.

```bash
echo '<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.service.http" level="WARN"/>' | yq --input-format xml '.AsyncLogger | .+@name + "," + .+@level'
```

**Output**

```
org.mule.service.http,WARN
```